# The app's external storage became hidden when I upgraded from Android 13 to Android 14

Tags: android-external-storage, android-14

I have two Android apps, and when I upgraded from Android 13 to Android 14, the external folder (accessed via the getExternalFilesDir()) became hidden for one of my apps. However, these folders are still visible for other apps. By 'visible,' I mean that when the phone is connected to the PC and the USB mode is chosen as File Transfer.

I am aware of the existence of the hidden folder because I can write to and read from it. It has become hidden on updating from Android 13 to 14 on my Pixel and on other users' Pixel phones.

What can be the reason that a specific external storage app folder becomes hidden while other app folders are still visible?

Comment: I am also having this problem with three of my apps. It started happening when I upgraded my phone - the directories are visible on the old phone. They cannot been seen via an 'ls' in 'adb shell'.